# What should come in yourJSON string?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to sort the event which I created using post method according to the price. After searching, I came up a solution by I don't know what to send in json.parse? I am new to this. Help me. Is this approach correct or there is any other method?

**server.js**

```
var express= require('express');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var config=require('./config');
var app= express();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var lodash= require('lodash');
var underscore= require('underscore');
//var User=require('./database/user')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db',function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("connected!");
    }
});
//res.json({message:"     " })
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true })); //if false then parse only strings
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));//log all the requests to the console
var api=require('./app/routes/api')(app,express,underscore,lodash);
app.use('/api',api);
app.get('*',function(req,res){
  //  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});   // * means any route

app.listen(config.port,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("The server is running");
    }
});
//module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
var User= require('../models/user');
var Event=require('../models/event');
var config=require('../../config');

var secret=config.secretKey;

module.exports=function(app,express,underscore,lodash) {
    var api = express.Router();
api.post('/eventfeed', function (req, res) {
        var event = new Event({
            name: req.body.name,
            location: req.body.location,
            description: req.body.description,
            price: req.body.price,
            rating: req.body.rating
        });

        event.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json({
                message: 'Event created!'
            });
        });
    });
    api.get('/event', function (req, res) {
        Event.find({}, function (err, event) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.json(event);
        });
    });
 api.get('/sortby_price',function(req,res){

    Event.find({}, function (err, event) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
      res.json(event);
    });
        var o=JSON.parse(???????)
        var ascending=true;//change to false for descending
      o.sort(function(a,b) {
            return (a.price - b.price)*(ascending?1:-1);
        });

 //variable "o" now contains our sorted object.
        var json = JSON.stringify(o);//convert back to a string
//now do something with either the "o" object or "json" string
        res.json(json);
    });

        return api;

}
```

**event.js**

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var  EventSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    location: String,
    description: String,
    price: Number,
    rating: Number
});
module.exports= mongoose.model('Event',EventSchema);
//module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse and stringify so much in the same code. `res.json()` already stringifies an object before sending it to the client.

Your *sortby_price* route can be simplified to this:

```
api.get('/sortby_price', function (req, res) {
    Event.find({}, function (err, events) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }

        var ascending = true;//change to false for descending
        events.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a.price - b.price) * (ascending ? 1 : -1);
        });

        res.json(events);
    });
});
```